# GeoWebCache and osmdroid

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I've got a GeoWebCache [geo server](http://82.146.41.127:8080/geoserver/gwc/) and now I want to use that as tile source for my android app. How can I do that? Is that even possible? My effort:

```
    mResourceProxy = new ResourceProxyImpl(this.getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext());              
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);       

    final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(this
            .getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("es09", null, 3, 14,
            256, ".png", tilesURL);
    tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
    final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, this
            .getActivity().getBaseContext());   

    mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);

    mapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(this.mMyLocationOverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();
```

Where `tilesURL` is `http://82.146.41.127:8080/geoserver/gwc/`. It results

> 03-02 12:01:25.195: W/o*.o*.t*.m*.MapTileDow*(900): Problem
>   downloading MapTile: /14/10434/5118 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad
>   Request

Also, what kind of URL should I use? I've found [tms](http://82.146.41.127:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/)

Comment: what is your tilesURL? is it valid?

Comment: @AmrutBidri, tilesURL is http://82.146.41.127:8080/geoserver/gwc/.

Comment: but it is array of String. can we set only one link there?

Comment: @AmrutBidri, yes, you are right. That's an array with one element.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use MapBox SDK for this.
You can set the geo server link to WebSourceTileLayer later set it to tile source

Kinda Simple!!

Added the code for your reference

```
if (layer.equalsIgnoreCase("OpenStreetMap"))
{
    source = new WebSourceTileLayer(
            "openstreetmap",
            "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
        .setName("OpenStreetMap")
        .setAttribution("Â© OpenStreetMap Contributors")
        .setMinimumZoomLevel(1)
        .setMaximumZoomLevel(18);
} 
mv.setTileSource(source);
```

Comment: Is that thing compatible with GeoWebCache server? Also, could you please check it in your app?

Comment: hey yes it is compatible to GeoWebCache server, you can go ahead on this

Comment: Did you try that? Also, what kind of url? http://82.146.41.127:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0 or  http://82.146.41.127:8080/geoserver/gwc?